# Flutter: CustomPainter paint method gets called several times instead of only once

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, graphics, flutter-layout

I have a simple app that draws via a `CustomPainter` a red or green circle on a canvas, depending on which button is pressed in the `AppBar`:

[image: Red Circle]
[image: Green Circle]

The class `ColorCircle` extends `CustomPainter` and is responsible for drawing the colored circle:

```dart
class ColorCircle extends CustomPainter {
  MaterialColor myColor;

  ColorCircle({@required this.myColor});
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    debugPrint('ColorCircle.paint, ${DateTime.now()}');
    final paint = Paint()..color = myColor;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), 100, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

The drawing of the different colors works fine, but when I click (only once!) or hover over one of the buttons, the `paint` method gets called several times:

[image: Debugmessage]

---

Further implementation details:
I use a `StatefulWidget` for storing the `actualColor`. In the build method `actualColor` is passed to the `ColorCircle` constructor:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MaterialColor actualColor = Colors.red;
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() => actualColor = Colors.red),
            child: Text('RedCircle'),
          ),
          OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() => actualColor = Colors.green),
            child: Text('GreenCircle'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(300, 300),
          painter: ColorCircle(myColor: actualColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The complete source code with a running example can be found here: [CustonPainter Demo](https://dartpad.dev/2993044a5769a4c4e81b158c271f2c86)

---

So why is `paint` called several times instead of only once? (And how could you implement it so that `paint` is called only once?).

Comment: Actually the repaint is happening whenever you hover the mouse above any of the buttons, or at least when you hover from one button to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A poor solution might be to add a `RepaintBoundary` around the hover Widgets:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MaterialColor actualColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Rebuilding with $actualColor');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CustomPainter Demo'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: OutlinedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => actualColor = Colors.red);
                },
                child: Text('RedCircle')),
          ),
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: OutlinedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => actualColor = Colors.green);
                },
                child: Text('GreenCircle')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(300, 300),
          painter: ColorCircle(myColor: actualColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then, to properly define the `shouldRepaint` method of the `ColorCircle` (currently returning `false`):

```
@override
bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return (oldDelegate as ColorCircle).myColor != myColor;
}
```

This seems to be a really poor solution. I would be interested to know of a better, more sustainable answer.

### Full source code with `RepaintBoundary` workaround

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CustomPainter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ColorCirle extends CustomPainter {
  MaterialColor myColor;

  ColorCirle({@required this.myColor});
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    debugPrint('ColorCircle.paint, ${DateTime.now()}');
    final paint = Paint()..color = myColor;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), 100, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return (oldDelegate as ColorCirle).myColor != myColor;
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MaterialColor actualColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CustomPainter Demo'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: OutlinedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => actualColor = Colors.red);
                },
                child: Text('RedCircle')),
          ),
          RepaintBoundary(
            child: OutlinedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black)),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => actualColor = Colors.green);
                },
                child: Text('GreenCircle')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size(300, 300),
          painter: ColorCirle(myColor: actualColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `RepaintBoundary` does not seem to work. The color is not changing when the buttons are clicked.

Comment: Correct. Sorry. I will check that.

Comment: Interestingly, RepaintBoundary works but the other way around. If you add a RepaintBoundary around the action buttons as in my updated answer. But this is really not practical. I will add a bounty to your question as I am interested in the answer too.

Comment: Sorry no solution for now other then this as issue is still pending at framework level: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49298

Answer (score 17):

All you need to do is to warp the `CustomPaint` with `RepaintBoundary`

```
   Center(
    child: RepaintBoundary(
      child: CustomPaint(
        size: Size(300, 300),
        painter: ColorCircle(myColor: actualColor),
      ),
    ),
```

By default `CustomPainter` is in the same layer as every other widget on the same screen so it's paint method will get called if any other widget on the same screen repaint.
To fix this we can isolate  the `CustomPainter` with `RepaintBoundary` so any repainting outside this `RepaintBoundary` wont effect it, or we can fix it by warping other widgets that would repaint with `RepaintBoundary` so they won't effect any other widgets (including the `CustomPainter` widget) when they get repaint, however it's better to just warp the `CustomPainter` with the `RepaintBoundary` instead of warping multiple widgets with `RepaintBoundary` since it's costly and sometimes have no effect.

You can get a better view and understanding of this by enabling [Highlight repaints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector#highlight-repaints) in the `DevTools`.

Comment: It works! but why?

Comment: From the docs for RepaintBoundry:
This widget creates a separate display list for its child, which can improve performance if the subtree repaints at different times than the surrounding parts of the tree.

Basically, you're telling the widget tree to leave children of this Boundry alone when other widgets change nearby

Comment: @KevinBloom Exactly